# Popup datepicker locked behind popup dialog

Tags: angular

My date picker dialog is locked behind my popup dialog box. My dialog box contains a form with a date field. When I click to select a date the datepicker goes behind the dialog box. Immmediately I close the dialog box the date picker dialog is also gone. Cant figure out this one
I could use some help here.

This is where I make the call to the popup dialog

```
editEducationOfficeStaffDetails(staffID: string) {
    this.dialogService.addDialog(EditEducationOfficeStaffComponent, { ID: staffID, title: "Edit: " + staffID });  
}
```

This is the popup dialog component

```
export class EditEducationOfficeStaffComponent extends DialogComponent<PromptModel, EducationOfficeStaff> implements PromptModel, OnInit {
ID: string;
title: string;
editStaff: EducationOfficeStaff;
Date: Date;
constructor(dialogService: DialogService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private staffService: StaffService) {
    super(dialogService);
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.GetEducationOfficeStaff(this.ID);
}
GetEducationOfficeStaff(staffID: string) {
    //this.myname = staffID;
    this.staffService.GetNewEducationOfficeStaff(staffID)
        .subscribe((res: EducationOfficeStaff) => {
            this.editStaff = res;
        })
}
apply() {
    //this.result = this.message;
    this.close();
}

isRequired = false;
isDisabled = false;
isOpenOnFocus = false;
isOpen = false;
type: string = 'date';
types: Array<any> = [
    { text: 'Date', value: 'date' },
    { text: 'Time', value: 'time' },
    { text: 'Date Time', value: 'datetime' }];

date: Date = null;
minDate: Date = null;
maxDate: Date = null;

openDatepicker() {
    this.isOpen = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.isOpen = false;
    }, 1000);
}

setDate() {
    this.date = new Date();
}
```

}

finally, this is the form containing the popup date picker

```
 <div class="modal-body">
        <form *ngIf="editStaff" class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="AddNewEducationOfficeStaff()" #editOfficeStaffForm="ngForm" style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:20px;margin-right:30px">
            <fieldset>
                <!--<legend>Enter Country Details</legend>-->
                <!--<div class="row" style="padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:10px">
                    <img md-card-md-image class="image" style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:20px" />
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" #staffPic type="file" (change)="changeListner($event)" style="margin-left:20px" />
                </div>-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <md-input-container style="width:100%">
                            <input mdInput name="staffID" placeholder="Click Here To Enter Staff ID"
                                   [(ngModel)]="editStaff.StaffID" required id="staffID" style="width: 100%"
                                   #staffID="ngModel">

                            <div [hidden]="staffID.valid || staffID.pristine"
                                 class="alert alert-danger">
                                Staff is required
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <md-input-container style="width:100%">
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Click Here To First Name"
                                   [(ngModel)]="editStaff.FirstName" name="firstName" id="firstname" required style="width: 100%"
                                   #firstName="ngModel">
                            <div [hidden]="firstName.valid || firstName.pristine"
                                 class="alert alert-danger">
                                First Name is required
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <md-input-container style="width:100%">
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Click Here To Enter Last Name"
                                   [(ngModel)]="editStaff.LastName" name="lastname" required id="lastname" style="width: 100%"
                                   #lastname="ngModel">
                            <div [hidden]="lastname.valid || lastname.pristine"
                                 class="alert alert-danger">
                                Last Name is required
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <md-input-container style="width:100%">
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Click Here To Enter Email Address"
                                   [(ngModel)]="editStaff.Email" name="email" id="email" required style="width: 100%"
                                   #email="ngModel">

                            <div [hidden]="email.valid || email.pristine"
                                 class="alert alert-danger">
                                Email Address is required
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <md-input-container style="width:100%">
                            <input mdInput name="position" placeholder="Click Here To Enter Position"
                                   [(ngModel)]="editStaff.Position" required id="position" style="width: 100%"
                                   #position="ngModel">

                            <div [hidden]="position.valid || position.pristine"
                                 class="alert alert-danger">
                                Position is required
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <!--<md-checkbox *ngFor="let role of roles" class="example-margin"
                             name="role.Name"
                             (change)="roleSelected(role)"
                             [align]="align"
                             [(ngModel)]="role.selected">
                    {{role.Name}}
                </md-checkbox>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <md2-datepicker placeholder="Select Date"
                                        name="DOB"
                                        [(ngModel)]="date"
                                        [required]="isRequired"
                                        [disabled]="isDisabled"
                                        [openOnFocus]="isOpenOnFocus"
                                        [isOpen]="isOpen"
                                        [type]="type"
                                        [min]="minDate"
                                        [max]="maxDate"
                                        #dateControl="ngModel" 
                                        ngDefaultControl>
                        </md2-datepicker>
                        <!--<div class="input-group date">
                            <md-input-container style="width:100%">
                                <input mdInput placeholder="Click Here To Enter Date Of Birth"
                                       [(ngModel)]="dateValue" name="DOB" id="DOB" required
                                       value="{{date | date:'MM/dd/yy'}}" (click)="open()"
                                       #DOB="ngModel">
                            </md-input-container>
                            <span class="input-group-addon " style="cursor:pointer" (click)="open()">
                                <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>-->
                        <!--<div class="dp-popup" *ngIf="showDatepicker">
                            <datepicker [(ngModel)]="dt" [minDate]="minDate" name="DOB" [showWeeks]="false" (selectionDone)="onSelectionDone($event)"></datepicker>
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="today()">Today</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <!--<div class="input-group date">
                            <md-input-container style="width:100%">
                                <input mdInput placeholder="Click Here To Enter Employment Start Date"
                                       [(ngModel)]="startDateValue" name="startDate" id="startDate" required
                                       value="{{date | date:'MM/dd/yy'}}" (click)="startDateOpen()"
                                       #startDate="ngModel">
                            </md-input-container>
                            <span class="input-group-addon " style="cursor:pointer" (click)="startDateOpen()">
                                <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dp-popup" *ngIf="showStartDatepicker">
                            <datepicker [(ngModel)]="sdt" [minDate]="minDate" name="startDate" [showWeeks]="false" (selectionDone)="startDateOnSelectionDone($event)"></datepicker>
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="startDateToday()">Today</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="startDateclear()">Clear</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <!--<div class="col-md-6">
                        <md-select placeholder="Select Office" style="width:100%"
                                   id="administructureID" name="administructureID" class="dropdown"
                                   (ngModelChange)="onOfficeSelect($event)"
                                   [(ngModel)]="educationOfficeStaff.AdministructureID">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let struct of structs" [value]="struct.AdministrativeStructureID">
                                {{ struct.AdminStructName }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-select>
                    </div>-->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <md-radio-group [(ngModel)]="Gender"
                                        (change)="GenderSelected($event.value)" name="genderOption" class="example-margin"
                                        [value]="editStaff.Gender"
                                        [align]="isAlignEnd ? 'end' : 'start'">
                            <md-radio-button name="genderOption" value="Male">
                                Male
                            </md-radio-button>
                            <md-radio-button name="genderOption" value="Female">
                                Female
                            </md-radio-button>
                        </md-radio-group>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p></p>
                        <button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="editOfficeStaffForm.reset()">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p></p>
                        <button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="UpdateEducationOfficeStaff();editOfficeStaffForm.reset()" [disabled]="!editOfficeStaffForm.form.valid || !editOfficeStaffForm.form.dirty">Submit</button>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you can post, or a plnkr perhaps?

Comment: Errmm yeah, I may have to do some reshuffling to piece them together

Comment: I have looked at acouple of similar issues here. It appears the problem is css related. some thing to do with z-index. Beig quite new to angular 2, just not sure were to go poking

Comment: Yes, it most definitely sounds like a z-index issue. (I'm guessing you're using an early version on angular 2 material date picker?) Due to the CSS encapsulation used, your best bet may be to add a small patch in your style.css to fix the issue until a more stable version of the date picker is released, but without being able to see/reproduce the issue, I can't tell you what the patch would/should be for certain.

Comment: @SteveG. Just did some update to the original issue with some code. hope it helps resolve my my problem

Comment: It mostly a CSS issue. So post your CSS code here. Also try to replicate same issue in a new plunker or code pen. Then share the link in this way we can help you quickly.

Comment: @SteveG. Tried to setup the plunkr but could not get it working. here is the link "https://plnkr.co/edit/KI0433yF3M5vh3DzT05o?p=preview"

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so this was far easier to resolve than I had thought. Not sure if I did the right thing but it seems to be working.

I decided to check out the content of the datepicker.scss. I copied and made the following changes to the z-index which originally had a value of only 1000. I replaced the "1000 " with "9999999 !important". I pasted this code in a separate css file

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
 position: fixed;
z-index: 999999 !important;
}

.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999999 !important;
}

.cdk-overlay-pane {
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: auto;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 z-index: 9999999 !important;
}

.cdk-overlay-backdrop {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 9999999 !important;
 pointer-events: auto;
 transition: opacity 400ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
opacity: 0;
}
```